# Moving html element containing contentEditable to another branch in dom without losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, contenteditable

I hope you can help with this problem.

I have the following html structure (simplified) which represents two fixed-height pages in a document with headers, footers, a body and a number of "DataItems" (3 readonly, 1 editable) within that body.  There are also a "Summary" and "Add New" DataItems.

I need to be able to move a DataItem's block of html (that may contain a contentEditable element) into another position in the document.  However, I need to do so without losing focus to the contentEditable element if it is that which is being moved.

This action is triggered whilst the user is typing into the contentEditable HTML Editor and the DataItem that they are typing into gets taller.  As it does so, when the bottom DataItem starts to overlap the footer, it gets pushed down to the next page.  A bit like typing into a table cell in MS Word that isn't allowed to break across pages.

I can get a partial solution working with jQuery.  This moves next sibling DataItems from the first page to the second page as a previous sibling grows in height, but the problem with this is that when I then go to move the DataItem which has focus, it loses focus and breaks the user's flow of typing.  I have tried putting focus back to the contentEditable div after moving it, but issues with selection and range and not being able to find the cursor position plus issues with the scrollbars jumping despite them being reset back have proved that solution to be too unreliable.

I therefore tried a different approach which was to move all html content between the last DataItem of the first page and the first DataItem (if any) of the next page to a position before the last data item, in the hope that doing so would prevent the html content editor from losing focus, but still give the impression that the DataItem has moved down to the second page.

The functionality I've tried (and failed) to achieve is to cut the html between the "start-here" and "end-here" divs and move it to the "paste-here" div.  The divs are just there as placeholders to show what should be moved.

However, despite trying various methods using jQuery dom manipulation and RegEx string replacement I can't seem to come up with a solution that doesn't involve replacing the common ancestor - which is the "Pages" div - and hence having to replace the current contentEditable - and hence losing focus.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this and retain focus so the user can continue typing uninterrupted?

Regards,
Jeremy :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
.Document
{
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

.Pages
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid yellow;*/
}

.PortraitPage
{
    height:29.7cm;
    width:21cm;
    background: #ffffff;
    position:relative;
}
       .FirstPage
    {
        border: 1px dotted black;
    }

    .ExtraPage
    {
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        border: 1px dotted black;
    } 

.PageHeader
{
    border: 0px dotted #e2e2e2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 18cm;
    left:0cm;
}

.PageBody
{
    border: 1px dotted #c2c2c2;
    position:absolute;
    top:4.5cm; /* this needs to be whatever the height of the header is */
    width: 18cm;
    left:1.5cm;
    /*min-height:22cm;*/
}

.PageFooter
{
    border: 1px dotted #e2e2e2;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 18cm;
    left:1.5cm;
}

.PageSeparator
{
    background: #999999;
    height: 1cm;
    width: 21cm;   
}
.InvoiceItemsForm
{
    position: relative;
    /*top: 2.5cm;*/
}

/* This prevents the space added in contentcell divs in the html entry cell just for the PageEditor */
.InvoiceItemsForm div
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.LineItem_Panel_ReadOnly
{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.LineItem_Panel_ReadOnly_Hover
{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.LineItem_Panel_Edit
{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
}


.LineItem_Panel_Insert
{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoicePage" class="Page FirstPage PortraitPage">
        <div class="FirstHeader PageHeader">
            First Page Header
        </div>
        <div class="ExtraHeader HiddenExtraPageSection">
            Hidden ExtraPage Header that is copied when a new page is created
        </div>
        <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoicePageBody" class="PageSection Body PageBody">
            <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoiceItemsForm" class="InvoiceItemsForm DataSection">
                <div id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl0_pnlLineItemReadOnly" class="DataItem LineItem_Panel_ReadOnly InvoiceLineItem">
                    <div class="LineItem_Panel_HTMLContent">
                        <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl0_lblHTMLContent">
                            <p>
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                            <p>
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl1_pnlLineItemReadOnly" class="DataItem LineItem_Panel_ReadOnly InvoiceLineItem">
                    <div class="LineItem_Panel_HTMLContent">
                        <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl1_lblHTMLContent">
                            <p>
                                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
                            <p>
                                bbbbbbbbbb</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl2_pnlLineItemReadOnly" class="DataItem LineItem_Panel_ReadOnly InvoiceLineItem">
                    <div class="LineItem_Panel_HTMLContent">
                        <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl2_lblHTMLContent">cccccccccccccc</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl3_pnlLineItemEdit" class="DataItem LineItem_Panel_Edit InvoiceLineItem">
                    <div id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl3_pnlHTMLEditor" class="HTMLEditorPanel">
                        <div style="width: 126px; height: 20px;" id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl3_txtHTMLContent$HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior_ExtenderContainer"
                            class="unselectable ajax__html_editor_extender_container">
                            <input style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl3_txtHTMLContent"
                                name="ctl00$phContent$lvLineItems$ctrl3$txtHTMLContent" value="ddddddddddddd"
                                type="text" autocomplete="off">
                            <div style="height: 21px; overflow: auto; clear: both;" id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_ctrl3_heeHTMLContent_ExtenderContentEditable"
                                class="ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor" contenteditable="true">
                                <p>
                                    ddddddddddddd</p>
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="DataItem">
                    <p>
                        Click <a id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_lbAddLineItem" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$phContent$lvLineItems$lbAddLineItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>
                            here</a> to add a new Data Item</p>
                </div>
                <div id="paste-here"></div>
                <div class="DataItem InvoiceTotals">
                    <div class="InvoiceSubTotal">
                        Sub Total: <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_lblInvoiceSubTotal">18,110.00</span></div>
                    <div class="InvoiceVATTotal">
                        VAT Total: <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_lblInvoiceVATTotal">3,111.00</span></div>
                    <div class="InvoiceTotal">
                        Invoice Total: <span id="ctl00_phContent_lvLineItems_lblInvoiceTotal">21,221.00</span></div>
                </div>
                <div id="start-cut"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="FirstFooter PageFooter">
            First Page Footer
        </div>
        <div class="ExtraFooter HiddenExtraPageSection">
            Hidden ExtraPage Footer that is copied when a new page is created
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoicePage" class="Page ExtraPage PortraitPage">
        <div class="ExtraHeader PageHeader">
            Extra Page Header
        </div>
        <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoicePageBody" class="PageSection Body PageBody">
            <div id="ctl00_phContent_pnlInvoiceItemsForm" class="InvoiceItemsForm DataSection">
                <div id="end-cut"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ExtraFooter PageFooter">
            Extra Page Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason you have to reparent anything to achieve the effect you want.  Instead of trying to rely on the browser being smart enough to render things where you want them, which will prove to be inconsistent between browsers and possibly different versions of the same browser, I would suggest using CSS and javascript to explicitly position the items.  When the text the user enters gets too long to fit in the space provided, you can use `node.style.top=newY; node.style.left=newX;` to reposition it, and `node.style.height=newHeight; node.style.width=newWidth;` to resize it however large it needs to be.  These methods don't require the browser to remove and re-insert the element, so focus is not lost, nor is text selection or cursor position.